# How can I pass a list of selected checkbox items and pass to the next View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I am listing Movie items in a view and want to know how I can pass any of those movies that are selected via a checkbox to another view, say the SelectedMovies view.

**My current Model:**

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Movies()
{
        return View(rc.GetAll().OrderBy(m => m.Name));
} 
public ActionResult SelectedMovies()
{
        return View();
}
```

**Movies View:**

```
 @model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Movie>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SelectedMovies","Site"))
 {
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <li>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)

         @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.isSelected)  
      </li>
    }
 }
```

The SelectedMovies view will just be a view with the items that were checked in the Movies View.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. you can save the selected item in your DB and repopulate the view and it will have the selected items. please provide more insight

Comment: I did a slight edit, not sure how to make it any more clearer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sachu(+1 rep if I could) I was able to solve my problem. It may or may not be the best solution but for now it gives me the result i want.

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedMovie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And instead of using the @Html.CheckBoxFor is used the standard

```
<input id="chk-@item.MovieID" type="checkbox" name="chk_movie" value="@item.MovieID" />
```

And for the ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectedMovies(IList<int> chk_movie)
{
    List<SelectedMovie> list = new List<SelectedMovie>();
    for (int i = 0; i < chk_movie.Count; i++ )
    {
         SelectedMovie sm = new SelectedMovie();
         Movie m = new Movie();
         m = RestClient.GetById(chk_movie[i]);
         sm.MovieID = m.MovieID;
         sm.Name = m.Name;
         list.Add(sm);
    }
    return View(list);
}
```

Hope this helps anyone with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

check the below code..hope it helps

In the view, give all your checkbox the same name and a unique value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="movie_id" value="@item.MovieID" > 

In your controller  pass an IList with the name of the checkbox.

public ActionResult display_selected_movies(IList<string> movie_id)
{
......
}
```

You will get a list of the values of only those checkbox that were selected.

Comment: Never mind I got it I had to use the name of the input, this helps me pass the ID across.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}
```

Then in View

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsSelected)
```